# URL lookup not working with update and retrieve

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In the url `/users/*username` I should be able to access each user by its username, the problem is that it isn't working how it's supposed to, doesn't matter what I write in `*username` it will update/delete the current logged user.

Example:
I could update the user "admin", through /users/123/, even though 123 is clearly not admin or any other existing user.

Here it's the User View with the methods that are not working the way I intended:

```py
class UserViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                  mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                  mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                  viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    lookup_field = 'username'

    queryset = User.objects.all()

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action in ['signup', 'login',]:
            permissions = [AllowAny]
        elif self.action in ['retrieve', 'update', 'destroy']:
            permissions = [IsAuthenticated, IsSameUser]
        else:
            permissions = [IsAuthenticated]
        return [p() for p in permissions]


    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(UserViewSet, self).retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
        data = response.data
        return Response(data=data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = UserModelSerializer(request.user, data=request.data, partial=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Users URL:

```
""" Users URLs """

# Django
from django.urls import include, path
# Django REST Framework
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
# Views
from users.views import UserViewSet

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users/', UserViewSet, basename='users')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it will update/delete the current logged user.

Of course

Your update method is:

```py
def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = UserModelSerializer(request.user, data=request.data, partial=True)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

where `request.user` is logged in user.

---

#### Correct code is something like:

```py
class UserViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                  mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                  mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                  viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    lookup_field = 'username'

    queryset = User.objects.all()

    ...
    
    def update(self, url_username, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            user_object = self.queryset.get(username=url_username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
             Response({'error': 'not found'}, status=404)
        serializer = UserModelSerializer(user_object, data=request.data, partial=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Also you need to add `url_username` in URL path:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    path('users/<str:url_username>', update_user)
]
```

Here

- `user_object` is user that you want to update
- `request.data` is a new data that you want to set to existing user
- `url_username` is a `*username` part in `/users/*username` to get exact user

---

#### Update 1: answer on question →

> I'm using DRF default router (updated the post and added what my
> urls.py looks like), the URL is generated taking the actions from the
> viewset, should I make all the URL like you did there? Like it says in
> the documentation all the URL patterns should be done automatically.

Oohhh... Django has million ways to implement API methods. And it is very complicated to reproduce behaviour inside my head according one piece of the code. The key of my answer is that you should use `username` placed in the url instead of `request.user`. Because `request.user` is logged-in user object (user that doing request).

At first, try to understand [UpdateModelMixin](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py)

This `Mixin` provides correct and standard `update()` method.
You trying to add standard `update()` method by including `mixins.UpdateModelMixin` and after that creating (overriding) own `update()`. So include `UpdateModelMixin` is useless.

If you want to use standard `update` method, just delete own `def update():` at all. And that may be solution.

If you want to create custom `update` method, remove `UpdateModelMixin`. It is unnecessary.

In this case try change update arguments like:

```py
def update(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        user_object = self.queryset.get(username=pk)
    ...
```

where `pk` will be `username` in your case (because you set `lookup_field = 'username'`)

As I said before it is hard to predict Django behaviour (actually I don't remember in details how works `pk`). Just try and see what happens.

If `pk` working as I expecting, you don't need to edit `urlpatterns`.

PS `def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):` also unnecessary if you including `RetreiveModelMixin`. `RetreiveModelMixin` adding `retrieve()` method for you.

Comment: I'm using DRF default router (updated the post and added what my urls.py looks like), the  URL is generated taking the actions from the viewset, should I make all the URL like you did there?  Like it says in the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/) all the URL patterns should be done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

in your UserSerializer serializer, you should add this meta class:

```py
    class Meta:
        lookup_field = 'username'
```